# Reference for upper bound $x^T A x \leq \lambda_{\max}(A) \|x\|^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, quadratic-forms, upper-lower-bounds

I need an upper bound for a quadratic form of the type:
$$x^T A x \leq \lambda_{\max}(A) \| x \|^2,$$
where $A$ is a real symmetric and non-singular matrix.

I recall that this can be done by defining $\lambda_{\max}(A)$ to be the maximum eigenvalue of $A$. Is this correct? If so, where can I find this result?

Comment: Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient

Comment: @FengShao Many thanks.

Comment: It isn't true, e.g. when $A=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0}$ or when $A$ hasn't any real eigenvalues. It's true, however, when $A$ is real symmetric and $x$ is a real vector.

Comment: @user1551 Good point. There are indeed necessary conditions for this upper bound to hold. In my case, $A$ is real symmetric and non singular. That's why I was not too worried about them.

Comment: @SnoopDogg You should write it in the post.

Comment: @FengShao Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's equivalent to analyze
$$\max_{x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus \mathbf{0} }  \frac{x^T A x}{x^T x}$$
Form linear algebra there exist $\Omega \in O(n)$ such that
$$\Omega^T A \Omega = \text{diag} \{\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdots,\lambda_{n}\}$$
where $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdots,\lambda_n$ are real numbers . And hence
$$
\max_{x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus \mathbf{0} }  \frac{x^T A x}{x^T x}
= \displaystyle \max_{\sum_{j=1}^{n} y_j^2 = 1} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \lambda_i y_i^2
$$
It's easy to see $$\max_{\sum_{j=1}^{n} y_j^2 = 1} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \lambda_i y_i^2 \le \max \lambda_i$$
and the equality holds when $x=\Omega^Ty=\Omega^T(y_1,y_2,\cdots,y_n)^T$ is the eigenvector of $\max \lambda_i$.

Thus $$ \max_{x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus \mathbf{0} }  \frac{x^T A x}{x^T x}= \max \lambda_i $$

Comment: Great. Any useful references?

Comment: @SnoopDogg I didn't know but Feng Shao gave you one in the comment.